# Augment a Python enum with a value taking parameters

Tags: python-3.x, enums, interface-design

I have a Python enum:

```py
class E(Enum):
  A = 1
  B = 2
```

It is part of a public interface, people pass `E.A` or `E.B` to various functions to specify some parameter. I want to augment this enum to add a third value, `C`, but this value only makes sense if you also pass a couple of additional parameters, `x` and `y`. So in addition to allowing my users to pass `E.A` or `E.B`, I want them to be able to pass e.g. `E.C(x=17,y=42)`, and have my code access the values of these parameters (here, 17 and 42).

What's the most "pythonic" way of achieving this? I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Pythonic way to achieve this, as you are trying to use `Enum` in a way other than which it was intended.  Let me explain:

First, an enum with more useful names:

```
class Food(Enum):
    APPLE = 1
    BANANA = 2
    CARROT = 3
```

Each enum member (so `APPLE` and `BANANA` above) is a singleton -- there will only ever be one `Food.APPLE`, one `Food.BANANA`, and one `Food.CARROT` (if you add it).  If you add an `x` and `y` attribute to `Food.CARROT`, then everywhere you use `Food.CARROT` you will see whatever `x` and `y` were last set to.

For example, if `func1` calls `func2` with `Food.CARROT(17, 19)`, and `func2` calls `func3` with `Food.CARROT(99, 101)`, then when `func1` regains control it will see `Food.CARROT.x == 99` and `Food.CARROT.y == 101`.

The way to solve this particular problem is just to add the `x` and `y` parameters to your functions, and have the functions verify them (just like you would for any other parameter that had restrictions or requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not fond of the approach of adding `x` and `y` parameters: I would need to do that for every single option I add to this enum that has parameters, so I would end up with massive argument lists and a lot of validation code. Isn't there a reasonable way of implementing the interface I want? I don't necessarily need the result to be subclassing `Enum` anymore.